# How to modifie the standard path of MySQL Workbench which points to where Backups shall be stored?

Tags: mysql-workbench

At the moment each time I want to make a dump of a database by MySQL Workbench it shows me this standard path as default:

```
/home/me/dumps/Dump20110810 # The date alters.
```

Since I have moved my dumps to a more suitable place (for me) it is getting annoying to change the path each time I want to dump something. I'd really like to have a setting option to not only give MySQL Workbench an other default path but perhaps turn the new template into something like:

```
/home/me/coding/myproject/Dump_database_name_2011-08-10_23:59
```

I poked arround in the settings but I couldn't find any switches for that. Perhaps someone more skilled with the Workbench knows how to alter this behavior?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The setting for the import/export folder is set by using the file menu 
Edit --> Preferences... --> Administrator ---> Export Directory Path

Restart MySQL Workbench for the changes to take effect.

There seems to be a bug which causes only the import folder to be updated, but if you also specify the folder path in the Data Export tool.

- Export to Dump Project Folder

Then it should work

Or update to MySQL Workbench 5.2.38 CE. In this version the bug mentioned above is fixed